# Autoeconders Keras with Variable Inputs

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, autoencoder

I have a keras code implementing an autoencoder like that:

```
ENCODING_DIM = 5

# input placeholder
input_img = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(320,))

# this is the encoded representation of the input
encoded = tf.keras.layers.Dense(35, activation='relu')(input_img)
encoded = tf.keras.layers.Dense(20, activation='relu')(encoded)
encoded = tf.keras.layers.Dense(ENCODING_DIM, activation='relu')(encoded)

decoded = tf.keras.layers.Dense(20, activation='relu')(encoded)
decoded = tf.keras.layers.Dense(35, activation='relu')(decoded)
decoded = tf.keras.layers.Dense(320, activation='sigmoid')(decoded)

autoencoder = tf.keras.models.Model(input_img, decoded)

encoder = tf.keras.models.Model(input_img, encoded)
encoded_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(ENCODING_DIM,))

decoder_layer = autoencoder.layers[-1]
#decoded_input = tf.keras.models.Model(encoded_input,decoder_layer(encoded_input))

autoencoder.compile(optimizer='nadam', loss='binary_crossentropy')
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
```

it works perfectly.

Now I would like to have variable input dimensions (e.g. the first vector [320x1], the second [280x1], etc...)

Now I try to do that:

```
ENCODING_DIM = 5

# input placeholder
input_img = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(None,))

# this is the encoded representation of the input
encoded = tf.keras.layers.Dense(35, activation='relu')(input_img)
encoded = tf.keras.layers.Dense(20, activation='relu')(encoded)
encoded = tf.keras.layers.Dense(ENCODING_DIM, activation='relu')(encoded)

decoded = tf.keras.layers.Dense(20, activation='relu')(encoded)
decoded = tf.keras.layers.Dense(35, activation='relu')(decoded)
decoded = tf.keras.layers.Dense(320, activation='sigmoid')(decoded)

autoencoder = tf.keras.models.Model(input_img, decoded)

encoder = tf.keras.models.Model(input_img, encoded)
encoded_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(ENCODING_DIM,))

decoder_layer = autoencoder.layers[-1]
#decoded_input = tf.keras.models.Model(encoded_input,decoder_layer(encoded_input))

autoencoder.compile(optimizer='nadam', loss='binary_crossentropy')
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
```

but it returns an error like:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-7764c4707491> in <module>()
     14 
     15 # this is the encoded representation of the input
---> 16 encoded = tf.keras.layers.Dense(35, activation='relu')(input_img)
     17 encoded = tf.keras.layers.Dense(20, activation='relu')(encoded)
     18 encoded = tf.keras.layers.Dense(ENCODING_DIM, activation='relu')(encoded)

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/core.py in build(self, input_shape)
    935     input_shape = tensor_shape.TensorShape(input_shape)
    936     if tensor_shape.dimension_value(input_shape[-1]) is None:
--> 937       raise ValueError('The last dimension of the inputs to `Dense` '
    938                        'should be defined. Found `None`.')
    939     last_dim = tensor_shape.dimension_value(input_shape[-1])

ValueError: The last dimension of the inputs to `Dense` should be defined. Found `None`.
```

How can I implement an autoencoder having different input dimensions?

Comment: Dense layer will create, in your case, 35 neurons where each will be connected to each input feature (out of 320). It will initialize the matrix of weight of size 35x320, for example. There is no way to initialize such a matrix when input size is not known, at least when it comes to dense layers. You will have to pad you inputs to some maximum possible input length (320?) to apply model as you define it.

Comment: Thank you. The pad solution seems to be the only way to solve the variable input dimensions

Comment: @y.selivonchyk I support your answer and propose to move it from comment to answer

Answer (score 0):

Dense layer will create, in your case, 35 neurons where each will be connected to each input feature (out of 320). It will initialize the matrix of weight of size 35x320, for example. There is no way to initialize such a matrix when input size is not known, at least when it comes to dense layers. You will have to pad you inputs to some maximum possible input length (320?) to apply model as you define it.